# How disable mousemove event in javascript jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an image and want to work with some events on it. Actually I want when a user (for the first) time

- clicks on any point of the image, the mousedown event does some code, then if the user
- continues pressing the mousedown, does some extra code and if the user
- triggers the mouseup event complete all codes by the mouseup event.

I am using the following code but it continues mousemove event even after user triggers mouseup. How is it possible to fix it?

```js
$("#myImage").on("mousedown", function (e) {
    console.log("mousedown");
    $(this).on("mousemove", function (e) {
        console.log(e.offsetX);
    }).on("mouseup", function (e) {
        console.log("mouseup");
        $(this).off("mousemove");
    });
});
```

```html
<img id = "myImage" src= "https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `.on("dragend", function() { console.log("ups..."); })` ;)

Comment: But I want move event to get (for example ) all the e.offsetX's when user moves the mouse pointer.

Comment: Doesn't change the fact that pressing the mouse and then moving it is a drag event. Replace `mouseup` with `dragend`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can't be solved with  tag.
Because if you drag the image, it can't get mouseover event.
How about using `<div> and background:url('..')`?